# Rails remove percentage symbol for numeric validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to validate a number but via jquery there is a % sign added to the interface

```
=> '10.4%'
```

So when i try to validate numericality it says that it is not a number

is there a rails way to validate this?

I've tried doing this in my model

```
 before_validation :convert_number

 private

 def convert_number
   self.number.to_f
 end
```

but it is still throwing the validation error that it is not a number

---

Comment: whats your number type, decimal or integer in schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, Issue is type of number is not decimal.

```
 before_validation :convert_number

 private

 def convert_number
   self.number = number.to_d
 end
```

Comment: could of sworn i tried this before.....but it works!  Now I have like 10 more fields I have to convert in the same way......number1, number2, number3 etc what would be the dryest way to convert all those fields in that method?

Comment: why just not convert it from front-end with JS and add validation to back-end ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to remove the % sign from the form data, I would recommend coercing the string to a float.

The string looks enough like a number to Ruby that coercion, in this case, works nicely.

When doing so, be assure to assign the new value to the attribute, like so:

```
def convert_number
  self.number = self.number.to_f
end
```

Just coercing the attribute the way you have it in the current `convert_number` won't assign the coerced value.

I might recommend writing a test to ensure this works on the range of values you expect from the form.

Comment: I've tried this and put it in a before_validation but it still throws an error saying its not a number

Comment: Can you update your question with this information, and post the code you used in the `before_validation` callback?

Comment: self.number = number.to_f

Answer (score 0):

you can trim the percentage and convert it to a float with a before_validation.  The thing is that since you are passing a string, you will have to convert to a number or float either way before actually validating.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html.

Comment: how can i trim the percentage?

Comment: I guess the parameter that gets pass is '10%' but it saves to the data base as 10.0 so when i tried to call number.chomp('%') I got an undefined method `chomp' for #<BigDecimal:7f882e09b830,'0.23E3',9(18)>

Answer (score 0):

I think you show use this syntax for this:

```
before_validation :convert_number
private
def convert_number
  self.number = self.number.chop
end
```